# Find $\min \int_0^{x\arctan x}\frac{e^{t-\cos t}}{1+t^{2023}}\mathrm dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

> Find the minimum value of : $$f(x) = \int_0^{x\arctan x}\frac{e^{t-\cos t}}{1+t^{2023}}\mathrm dt$$

Using FTC, we have ;

$$f'(x) = \frac{e^{x\arctan x - \cos (x\arctan x)}}{1+x\arctan x}.(\arctan x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1})$$

For $f$ to be minimum, $f' = 0\implies\arctan x = -\frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$

However, I can't proceed further and don't find it much useful.

This question appeared today in my test (JEE) for which I had an average of 3.5 minutes to solve it. But in such short time, I am failing to find a short and elegant method.

Comment: What you have said right now would have given the OP actual depression @Gonçalo (the chances of getting a good college are entirely dependent on this one exam in India) supposing they wrote the exam

Comment: @Gonçalo How can I skip such a trivial thing 

Comment: @An_Elephant, why did you write that $$f'(x) = \frac{e^{x\arctan x - \cos (x\arctan x)}}{1+x\arctan x}\!\cdot\!(\arctan x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1})\;\;?$$It should be $$f'(x) = \frac{e^{x\arctan x - \cos (x\arctan x)}}{1+(x\arctan x)^{\color{red}{2023}}}\!\cdot\!(\arctan x + \frac{x}{x^2 + 1})$$

Comment: @Angelo Aren't both same ?

Comment: India is the only country where we have to compete against other wildlife for seats in best college, good thing there is no Zoo animal reservation (just joking)

Comment: At least now you can answer your own question here. It's also worth noting that $1 + (x \arctan x)^{2023}$ is never zero, but that's easy to show.

Comment: Hint: the integrand is non-negative for $t\ge0$, while $x\arctan x$ is an even function minimized at $x=0$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes I get it. My brain just went somewhere else in exam :(

Comment: @aschepler Yes. I get it.

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller I don't think reservation really matters given that one has studied well (I'm myself a general elephant).  Anyway, I only attempted 51 out of total with many guesses. It went poor :(

Comment: Man why does no one get my jokes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Find the minimum value of :$$f(x)=\int_0^{x\arctan x}\frac{e^{t-\cos t}}{1+t^{2023}}\,\mathrm dt$$

Since $\;x\arctan x>0\;$ for any $\;x\neq0\;$ and $\;\dfrac{e^{t-\cos t}}{1+t^{2023}}>0\;$ for any $\;t\geqslant0\,,\;$ it follows that

$f(x)>0\;$ for any $\;x\neq0\,,\;$ hence

the minimum value of $\,f(x)\,$ is

$f(0)=0\,$.

Comment: What is the domain of f? Is it given here that $t\geq 0$ in the integrand?

Comment: @SungjinKim, the domain of $f(x)$ is $\Bbb R$, but $x\arctan x\geqslant0$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$, so it is sufficient to take into account $t\geqslant0$, indeed the interval of integration is $[0,x\arctan x]\subset\Bbb R_0^+.$